# Will Accepting ReSharper's Suggestion Ruin This Singleton?

Tags: c#, singleton, resharper

I was implementing a singleton with static initialization like this:

```
internal sealed class MySingleton
{
    private static readonly MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();

    public static MySingleton Instance => instance;

    private MySingleton()
    {
        // elided
    }
}
```

ReSharper squiggled the public property Instance and offered to convert it to an auto-property.  The result, if accepting the fix, looks like this:

```
internal sealed class MySingleton
{
    public static MySingleton Instance { get; } = new MySingleton();

    private MySingleton()
    {
        // elided
    }
}
```

Doesn't this "fix" make it so that every call to the Instance property will generate a brand new MySingleton, thus defeating the whole purpose, or is there something about static properties that ReSharper knows and I don't?

Comment: It's pretty easy to run that code and see if it in fact call the constructor each time the getter is called.  A breakpoint, or any side effect in the constructor, would make it very visible.

Comment: While this will work, you may experience multi-threading and performance issues using either of those snippets. I will log in to my PC shortly and provide a safer implementation using double locking to make it truly thread safe. While I love resharper some of the suggestions can usually be ignored and this would be an example where it doesn't really matter either way, though its important to be consistent with whatever you choose.

Comment: @mbrdev - Thanks; I am aware of the threading problems with this implementation but I'm curious what performance issues you're referring to.

Comment: @mbrdev Both solutions provided are entirely threadsafe.  There is no need for explicit locking at all.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I read the below article this morning and got the examples mixed up! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [read-only auto property](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#auto-property-enhancements), using a syntax that was introduced in C# 6.  The code on the right-hand side is executed only once, just to initially assign the value of the property.

Comment: Ah, I did not know the new read-only properties worked like that.  Is this only for auto properties?  I would expect if I had a body in the getter, it would execute it every time.

Comment: @bubbleking Try it and find out.

Comment: Actually now that I've read your link, I do recall that the read-only auto properties work like this.